# Transform matrix to get intersection point of line and plane

Tags: geometry

Give a point $Q[A, B, C]$ and a plane $Dx + Ey + Fz = 0$.

Now for any point $P[x, y, z]$, is there a matrix $M$ that can be used to get the intersection point of the line $PQ$ and the plane
(Say intersection point is $F, P \times M = F$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $n=[D,E,F]$ for the normal of the plane, you are looking for a $\lambda$ such that $$\langle n,Q+\lambda (P-Q)\rangle=0\,,$$ i.e. the scalar product between the normal and a generic point on the line equals zero at the point of intersection. Rewrite that to

\begin{align*}
\langle n,Q\rangle+\lambda\langle n,P-Q\rangle&=0\\
\lambda &= \frac{\langle n,Q\rangle}{\langle n,Q-P\rangle}
\end{align*}

At this point you see that $P$ is in the denominator; you are dividing by some quantity which depends on $P$. Expressing that as a matrix multiplication in affine geometry is a bit tricky.

There is however an approach which deals with divisions in geometry more elegantly, namely projective geometry. It uses homogeneous coordinates, so now you have $n=[D:E:F:0]$, $Q=[A:B:C:1]$ and $P=[x:y:z:1]$. Any multiple of any of these vectors describes the same object. This time a generic point on the line is any linear combination, so you have

\begin{align*}
\langle n, \lambda P+\mu Q\rangle &= 0 \\
\lambda\langle n,P\rangle+\mu\langle n,Q\rangle &= 0
\end{align*}

Here you have a one-dimensional space of solutions, and any one will represent the same geometric point of intersection. Pick $\lambda=\langle n,Q\rangle$ and $\mu=-\langle n,P\rangle$. The point of intersection was called $F$ in your question, but as that conflicts with one parameter of your plane, let's use $R$ instead.

$$R=\langle n,Q\rangle P-\langle n,P\rangle Q$$

If you treat your vectors as line vectors (as your use of notation suggests), you can write this as

$$R=n\cdot Q^T\cdot P - n\cdot P^T\cdot Q$$

as the scalar product is the product of a row vector with a column vector (the transpose of a row vector). Now we try to get the $P$ to the very left.

\begin{align*}
R &= P\cdot n\cdot Q^T - P\cdot n^T\cdot Q \\
R &= P\cdot\mathbf 1_4\cdot n\cdot Q^T - P\cdot n^T\cdot Q \\
R &= P\cdot\underbrace{\left(n\cdot Q^T\cdot\mathbf 1_4 - n^T\cdot Q\right)}_M
\end{align*}

The $n^T\cdot Q$ there is an outer product: column vector times row vector. It results in a $4\times4$ matrix. The left term $n\cdot Q^T$ is just a regular scalar product. To make that compatible for subtraction of a matrix, we multiply with the $4\times 4$ unit matrix $\mathbf 1_4$.

Going back to your notation you get that matrix $M$ as

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
BE+CF & -BD & -CD & -D \\
-AE & AD+CF & -CE & -E \\
-AF & -BF & AD+BE & -F \\
0 & 0 & 0 & AD+BE+CF
\end{bmatrix}$$

With this matrix you get $R=P\cdot M$ as the homogeneous coordinates of the point of intersection. Divide by the last coordinate to obtain $x,y,z$ coordinates in the first three coordinates.

One nice benefit of doing all of this projectively: if your plane is not through the origin, it still fits this picture: $n=[D,E,F,G]$ would describe a plane $Dx+Ey+Fz+G=0$.

Comment: How to calculate P dot M? I tried cross product and it turns out to be incorrent.

Comment: @WikiWang: Regular matrix multiplication. A $1\times 4$ matrix times a $4\times 4$ matrix. It might well be that I have a mistake somewhere, so if things don't work out, please double-check my derivation, make sure I actually computed the things I wrote.

Comment: Well actually I dont know how come $λ⟨n,P⟩+μ⟨n,Q⟩=0$ is true and anyway, after pick $λ=⟨n,Q⟩$ and $μ=−⟨n,P⟩$, how it turns out to be $R=⟨n,Q⟩P−⟨n,P⟩Q$? Sorry for my poor math, sign.

Comment: So matrix with G $M=\begin{bmatrix}
BE+CF+G & -BD & -CD & -D \\
-AE & AD+CF+G & -CE & -E \\
-AF & -BF & AD+BE+G & -F \\
-AG & -BG & -CG & AD+BE+CF
\end{bmatrix}$ seems to be alright. Strange thing in R language it has to be  M %*% P rather than  P %*% M.

Comment: @WikiWang: The way I read the [R Matrix multiplication docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Multiplication), a vector *should* be usable as the left hand side of a vector times matrix multiplication, and should get interpreted as a row vector. Could it be your vector is in fact a $4\times1$ matrix already? On the other hand, many mathematicians tend to think in column vectors, and doing matrix time vector products rather than the other way round. In that case you need to *transpose* the matrix discussed above.

Comment: transposed matrix with will do, `P %*% t(M)`, many thanks